# Should EF Core prevent me from inserting child entity if parent does not exist?

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework-core

I'm experimenting with Entity Framework Core. I have two models:

```
public class Child
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int ParentId { get; set; }
    public Parent Parent { get; set; }
}

public class Parent
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public List<Child> Childs { get; set; }
}
```

I'm adding a new `Child` into an empty database like this:

```
dbContext.Add(new Child {Name = "name", ParentId = 42});
```

There is no `Parent` with `Id = 42` in database obviously, but the child is stored anyway.

Is it normal behavior that EF Core lets me store a `Child` object with a non-existent `ParentId`? Can I configure EF Core to prevent that?

I tried to configure relationship between `Child` and `Parent` explicitly in `IEntityTypeConfiguration` but nothing changed.

Comment: I would expect you to get an error when you call `dbContext.SaveChanges()` if you have a FK setup

Answer (score 0):

One recommendation is that when using navigation properties ("Parent") I would avoid also defining FK properties alongside them in the entity. ("ParentId") Instead, use shadow properties for the FK.

```
public class Child
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Parent Parent { get; set; }
}

public class Parent
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public List<Child> Childs { get; set; } = new List<Child>();
}
```

EF will work out FKs by convention (I.e. a FK called ParentId for a navigation property of type Parent) or you can configure the relationship to use a particular FK name in the table.

The primary reason for this is to avoid situations where there are two sources of truth for a relationship:  child.ParentId and child.Parent.Id. This can lead to behaviour issues depending on whether the Parent navigation property is populated or not, and it also helps promote proper validation when performing things like inserts and updates.

To create a new Child for a parent:

```
var parent = _context.Parents.Single(x => x.Id == parentId);
var child = new Child { Name = name, Parent = parent };
_context.Children.Add(child);
_context.SaveChanges();
```

Alternatively you can manage parent-child relations through the parent:

```
var parent = _context.Parents
    .Include(x => x.Childs)
    .Single(x => x.Id == parentId);
parent.Childs.Add(new Child { Name = name });

_context.SaveChanges();
```

The reason to avoid having both FK and navigation property is that things like an update behaviour can vary depending on whether the navigation property is loaded or not. For instance, if a child record can be moved between parents and we have a parent ID of "1" that we want to change to "2":

```
using(var context = new AppDbContext())
{
    var child = _context.Children
        .Single(x => x.Id == childId);
    child.ParentId = 2;
    _context.SaveChanges();
}
```

This would work as expected, particularly because we are scoping the DbContext for just this operation. If the DbContext lifetime is a bit wider (I.e. per request) then this code might not work.  For instance the following examples:

```
using(var context = new AppDbContext())
{
    var child = _context.Children
        .Include(x => x.Parent)
        .Single(x => x.Id == childId);
    child.ParentId = 2;
    _context.SaveChanges();
}

using(var context = new AppDbContext())
{
    var parent = _context.Parents.Single(x => x.Id == 1); 
    // happens to be the Parent for our child below, just loading 
    // and tracking a reference, not using for this operation
    var child = _context.Children.Single(x => x.Id == childId);
    child.ParentId = 2;
    _context.SaveChanges();
}
```

You might expect that these would work and update the parent, but they won't. The parent reference will remain pointing at Parent ID 1. The reason is because when there is a navigation property loaded, it will take precedence in the change tracking to the FK property. When a reference is eager loaded that might be easy to anticipate, but it can also happen when the reference is not eager loaded if the DbContext happens to be already tracking the navigation property when the desired entity to update is loaded. This can result in unexpected and situational, intermittent errors or failures to change FK references. When something like a DbContext is scoped to a web request (no `using` scope as in the examples above) it is quite possible that earlier operations may sometimes result in references being loaded and tracked, resulting in that sometimes navigation properties are populated even when you don't eager load them. For that reason I highly recommend that when using navigation properties, update references using the navigation properties and use shadow properties for FKs.